# D3 zoom behavior prevent click event in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, d3.js

I add

```
d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw);
```

now the click event on node is not working in IE9.

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
            .on("click", click, true);
```

What can I do to get the click event working also in IE9?

//Jens

Comment: Strange: If I open a new tab in IE window the click event (on a node) is executed. Do I close the tab no click event is executed.

Please see my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrJones/trtKU/4/

Comment: I can't seem to make this work at all, in chrome. The zoom rectangle gobbles up the click events if it's in front, or never gets them if it's behind. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem on ie9 and ie10. The strange thing for me is: when I am opening second tab in ie the click events starting to work...

Answer (score 3):

By overriding mouseup.zoom (on mousemove) I was able to preserve click events in IE9.

```
var pan = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + panTranslate + ")")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function(d){
        panTranslate[0] += d3.event.translate[0];
        panTranslate[1] += d3.event.translate[1];
        pan.attr("transform", "translate(" + panTranslate + ")");
        d3.select(window).on("mouseup.zoom", function(){
            d3.select(window).on("mousemove.zoom", null).on("mouseup.zoom", null);
        });
        return true;
    })).on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```